# Save LyX bookmarks along with LyX file?

Tags: lyx

Say I've added a bookmark (by pressing Shift-F1) in v1.lyx. I can press Ctrl+1 to go to that bookmark.

I now save this file as v2.lyx. While I have v2.lyx open, I expect that Ctrl+1 again brings me that bookmark in the file v2.lyx. But instead, it brings me to the bookmark in v1.lyx.

Is there any way to do what I want? Or does this feature not exist yet in LyX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality does not exist in LyX. The only workaround is to manually edit the bookmarks. This information is stored in the "session" file inside your user directory (see Help > About in LyX for where this directory is). That file contains (among other things) the following contents:

```
[bookmarks]
0, 10, 1, /home/scott/Desktop/v1.lyx
1, 7, 3, /home/scott/Desktop/v1.lyx
```

You can just change "v1" to "v2.

I don't imagine this would be worth your time to do manually. If you happen to use Linux, starting with LyX 2.3.2 (which contains [this](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10712) enhancement), it would be possible to make this update automatically.

Edit: An enhancement request for this behavior has been opened [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11055).